# Как сделать перезарядку в игре?

Tags: javascript

Я пишу игру - танчики на php/js.
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы, зажимая пробел, пули не отрисовывались бесконечно, создавая хаос. Нужно как-то сделать между ними интервал в 2 секунды. Рекурсия не поможет.

```
//Добавляю в массив пулю
if(self.key == 32) {
       this.bullets.push(new Bullet(data.a, data.x, data.y, data.h, data.w));
}

//Отрисовываю их
for(bullet in this.bullets) {
    bullet = this.bullets[bullet];
    bullet.drawBullet();
    tank.isUpdated = true
}
```

Comment: в такнчиках на dendy было так, что пока твой снаряд еще летит, стрельнуть нельзя, попробуйте так =)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала сохрани время момента выстрела, когда нажмут на выстрел то в if проверь разницу интервала между последним и данным выстрелом,и если больше чем твой интервал то запускай функцию стрельбы  и обновляй счетчик))))

Comment: как в моем случаи сохранить время выстреля? я просто плохо шарю в временах на js

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime
Вот тут написно

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prev = new Date();
if(self.key == 32) {
        var cur = new Date();
       if((cur - prev) / 1000 >= 2) {
          prev = cur;
          this.bullets.push(new Bullet(data.a, data.x, data.y, data.h, data.w));
       }
}
```